# Indexed property is array of a type but I don't want an array

Tags: typescript

So I have this class:

```
export declare class Track {
    name: string;
    instrument: Instrument;
    notes: Note[];
    // more
}
```

I want to access to the `Note` class to use it in a variable

```
export declare class Note implements NoteInterface {
    midi: number;
    velocity: number;
    noteOffVelocity: number;
    //  more
};
```

I don't have direct access to it `Note`, so it must accessed it via `Track`, which can be accessed by using [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

```
const note: Track['notes']
```

However this means that `note` would be `Note[]` and it want `note` to be `Note` — not an array of `Note`s.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index the array with `number`.

```
const note: Track['notes'][number]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAOQPZngXjgbwL6krOASQDsBnMAJwFcBbGYsODHUUGADyiQsYBMYAxgBsAhhXjCRpUnAAqFEQIDWWUHHVxiIugC445CgEtiAcwDcajcYO16YPSRt0GFkBs0oYpPclQBtAF1XXBBQASQyRmJPPXlFJT8AcmjUUkSAv2JaACMYCgCmLGwgA)